# In a triangle $ABC$ with side $AB=AC$ and $\measuredangle BAC=20 ^\circ $. $D $ is a point on side $AC$ and $BC = AD$. Find $ \measuredangle DBC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Problem :** In a triangle $ABC$ with side $AB=AC$ and $\measuredangle BAC=20 ^\circ $.

$D $ is a point on side $AC$ and $BC = AD$. Find $ \measuredangle DBC$

**Solution:**

$AB =AC$

So  $ \measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle ABC$

$ \measuredangle ACB = \measuredangle ABC=80^\circ$ (Using angle sum property)

I am unable to continue from here.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Are we supposed to do this geometrically or by trig?

Comment: any method geometrically or by trig

Comment: My calculations lead me to weird stuff. Can x have multiple values?

Comment: NO, multiple values are not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a point inside the triangle such that $EB=EC=BC$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Since $\measuredangle{ABE}=\frac{180^\circ-20^\circ}{2}-60^\circ=20^\circ$, we can see that $\triangle{ABD}$ and $\triangle{BAE}$ are congruent.

Hence, $$\measuredangle{DBC}=\measuredangle{ABC}-\measuredangle{ABD}=\measuredangle{ABC}-\measuredangle{BAE}=80^\circ-10^\circ=\color{red}{70^\circ}.$$

Comment: How did you arrive at this construction?  Practice?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: I drew an equilateral triangle $BEC$ in order to "relate" $BC$ to $AD$. ($BC$ moves to $BE$ : $BC$ is "far" from $AD$, but $BE$ is "near" to $AD$ so that we can have triangles with these sides.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $ABC$ be the triangle with $O$ being the circumcentre. $AO$ is extended to meet $BC$ at $D$. $BO$ is extended to meet $AC$ at $E$. Let $F$ 
be the point on $AC$ such that $AF= BC$. 
Triangle $OAB$ is congruent to triangle $OAC$. 
Therefore $\angle BAO = \angle CAO = 10^{\circ}$.
Let $BD = a$, so $CD$ also equals $a$ 
therefore $AB = \frac{a}{\sin 10^{\circ}}$ 
Now applying sine rule in triangle $AEB$
$$ 
\frac{AE}{\sin 10^{\circ}} = \frac{AB}{\sin 150^{\circ}}
$$ 
Putting the value of $AB$ as $a/\sin 10^{\circ}$ 
We get 
$$
AE = \frac{a}{\sin 30^{\circ}} = 2a.
$$ 
We have $AF= BC = 2a$ 
Therefore $F$ and $E$ are the same point . 
Therefore 
$$
\angle ABF = \angle ABE = 10^{\circ}
$$

and hence
$$
\angle FBC = 80 - 10 = 70^{\circ}.
$$